# How to print an id get with document.getElementById?

Tags: javascript, dom

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fuctions.js"></script>
    <title>Count JS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="number" value="1" id="num" min="1" max="5"/>
        <button  onclick="getValue()">
            Submit
        </button>
    </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function getValue() {
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("num"));
alert(x);
```

}

I just want to print this value that I get using `document.getElementById`, but when I print appears it:

[image]

Can someone help?

Comment: You try to parse a HTML element as integer. This **must** fail.

Comment: Try to use this: this.getAttribute('id');

Comment: What made you think [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) returns the value of the input?

Comment: @FelixKling, It was a big mistake, I thought that using this I'd can get my input, I'm not read the docs about JS.

Comment: Well, you get the input *element*, but not the input *value* ;)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I wasn't paying attention in this detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.value` returns value from input, in your case, you try convert `DOMNode` to `Integer` that will return `NaN`

```
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value);
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/giletu/1/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 1):

Add `.value` after document.getElementById

```
function getValue() {
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value);
    alert(x);
}
```